# 複数のアプリケーションを動作させる場合のunicorn+nginxの設定

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

sinatraで作ったサイトをunicorn+nginxで公開していて、もう1つサイトを追加したいのですが、やり方がわからないので教えて下さい。

現在以下のようになっています。(関係ありそうな部分だけ抜粋しています)

unicornの設定

```
listen "/tmp/unicorn_server.sock", backlog: 1024
```

nginxの設定

```
# unicorn
upstream unicorn_server {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn_server.sock;
}


# サイトA
server {

  listen       80;
  server_name  site-a.com;
  root         /var/www/site-a/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
  }

}
```

これにサイトBを追加したいのですが、どのようにしたらよいのかまったくわかりません。

unicornをもう1つ立ち上げてlistenを新しく作り、サイトAのようにnginxに追加するのでしょうか?
それとも1つのunicornの中に複数のlistenをもたせるのでしょうか?

そもそもunicornって複数立ち上げられるのでしょうか。。。
初めてのことでよくわからない事だらけです。

参考になるサイト、もしくは具体的な設定例を教えていただけると助かります。

他に必要な情報があれば書き込むので言ってください。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

サイトB用のUnicornを別途起動する必要があります。その際、設定ファイルにサイトAとは異なるsockファイルを指定する必要があります。
（下の例では`/tmp/unicorn_server_b.sock`を指定しています。）

```
listen "/tmp/unicorn_server_b.sock", backlog: 1024
```

また、nginxの設定変更も必要です。設定ファイルにもサイトB用の設定を追記します。
（サイトAはsite-a.com、サイトBはsite-b.comというドメインを持っていると仮定）

```
# サイトA用設定
upstream unicorn_server {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn_server.sock;
}

server {

  listen       80;
  server_name  site-a.com;
  root         /var/www/site-a/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
  }

}

# サイトB用設定
upstream unicorn_server_b {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn_server_b.sock;
}

server {

  listen       80;
  server_name  site-b.com;
  root         /var/www/site-b/public;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://unicorn_server_b;
  }

}
```

Comment: なるほど!!素直な仕組みですね!!
うまくいきました。
ありがとうございます!!